# If the union is connected does that imply that the member sets are connected?

Tags: real-analysis

If $A \cup B$ is connected then does that imply $A$ and $B$ are connected ? I guess if it is disjoint union then member sets should be connected.

Comment: The reals are the union of the rationals and the irrationals.

Comment: "If the union of connected sets is connected does that imply that the member sets are connected?" - yes, it does.

Comment: @prasenjit: you have earned a significant amount of rep, so you aren't a new user. You must be aware that, particularly recently, there is an expectation that questions should include some context, such as what you have tried already. Questions that just state what looks like a standard homework problem tend to be put on hold.

Comment: @CarlMummert : I wanted to know whether it is true for disjoint union.

Comment: It is not even true for disjoint union.

Answer (score 3):

No: $A=(0,2)\cup(2,4)$ and $B=(1,3)\cup(3,5)$.

Comment: @njguliyev: if it is disjoint union then I guess $A$ and $B$ are connected. Is it correct ?

Comment: No, with the above $A$ let $B=\{2\}\cup\{4\}$.

Comment: @bof: I made a typing mistake in the title, corrected now.

Comment: @njguliyev: understood now.

Comment: @prasenjit In fact, **any** connected Hausdorff space with more than one point is the union of two disjoint disconnected subspaces.